# How to merge lists having all the columns similar

Tags: python, mysql, list, merge

I have these lists in python

```
['2015-02-09', '11:55:55.712', '0.000', '17', '10.5.164.81', '10.0.87.161', 53, 7788, '0', '1', '0', '133', '1']
['2015-02-09', '13:53:55.626', '0.000', '17', '10.132.67.12', '10.0.87.161', 53, 59110, '0', '1', '0', '87', '1']
['2015-02-09', '19:29:41.850', '0.000', '17', '10.150.12.241', '10.1.1.58', 53, 54801, '0', '1', '0', '155', '1']
['2015-02-10', '00:03:22.957', '0.000', '17', '10.0.228.231', '10.0.87.161', 53, 56803, '0', '1', '0', '84', '1']
['2015-02-10', '00:19:55.404', '0.000', '17', '10.195.0.225', '10.0.87.161', 88, 4338, '0', '1', '0', '127', '1']
['2015-02-10', '00:03:22.957', '0.000', '17', '10.0.228.231', '10.0.87.161', 53, 56803, '0', '1', '0', '84', '1']
```

I have to merge the lists if 4th 5th 6th (starting from 0 ) columns is the same.

That is if two rows has same `'10.0.228.231', '10.0.87.161', 53,` I have to make it into a single entry while adding the other columns.

Is it best to use python or do it in sql. How do i approach?

Comment: is you input is a list of list?

Comment: if two rows have those values the same, which of the other values do you want to use? or are they ALL going to be the same?

Comment: _"while adding the other columns."_  Show the desired output corresponding to your sample input.

Comment: Yes! my input is a list of lists .

Comment: @user1723766: Can you give sample output of final single entry after adding two list? Match may found more then two list also, so what will be output in this case?

Comment: there is date column, do you have add that too ?

Comment: If there are duplicate rows (two or more) . Ignore the date column (remove it) Mergge the duplicate rows and make it into one row considering unique (field_4, field_5, field_6)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care which of the rows is kept, and you want to prevent future duplicates, you can add a unique index over the three columns, and automatically delete conflicting rows:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE <table> ADD UNIQUE KEY uidx_1(field_4, field_5, field_6)
```

**edit**

Okay, so apparently you dont want to alter the table, it seems you just want to alter the output. Since you don't seem to care which of the other values are kept (and they all seem to be the same anyway, in your sample data), you can get away with the following:

```
select *
  from <table>
  group by field4, field_5, field_6;
```

You can choose which results to include (ie, remove the date) by specifying the exact fields you want in the select clause.

Note that due to the way group by works, you can't guarantee which row will be in the results, just that only ONE of the rows will be.  Without any further criteria on how to choose which fields from which row you want to survive the 'merge', this is probably your best bet

Comment: I do not want to ignore the duplicate fields instead i want to add field_7, field_8, field_9 , field_3, field_2 for the unique (field_4, field_5, field_6)

Comment: what if there are three duplicate rows?

Comment: If there are duplicate rows (two or more) . Ignore the date column (remove it) Mergge the duplicate rows and make it into one row considering unique (field_4, field_5, field_6)

Comment: so you only want this to happen when you access the data, you dont want it to be a permanent change to the data?

Comment: you're going to have to specify what you mean by 'merge'. can you show us two duplicate rows, and what you would like the resulting row to look like?

Answer (score 0):

a plain solution could be to use a dictionary, using columns 4,5 and 6 as a combined key.
Obviously it's still up to you to "sum" the values properly (see inline comment below). It may be better to convert the column strings to specific types to allow operator overloading.

```
ilist = [
         ['2015-02-09', '11:55:55.712', '0.000', '17', '10.5.164.81', '10.0.87.161', 53, 7788, '0', '1', '0', '133', '1'],
         ['2015-02-09', '13:53:55.626', '0.000', '17', '10.132.67.12', '10.0.87.161', 53, 59110, '0', '1', '0', '87', '1'],
         ['2015-02-09', '19:29:41.850', '0.000', '17', '10.150.12.241', '10.1.1.58', 53, 54801, '0', '1', '0', '155', '1'],
         ['2015-02-10', '00:03:22.957', '0.000', '17', '10.0.228.231', '10.0.87.161', 53, 56803, '0', '1', '0', '84', '1'],
         ['2015-02-10', '00:19:55.404', '0.000', '17', '10.195.0.225', '10.0.87.161', 88, 4338, '0', '1', '0', '127', '1'],
         ['2015-02-10', '00:03:22.957', '0.000', '17', '10.0.228.231', '10.0.87.161', 53, 56803, '0', '1', '0', '84', '1']
        ]

def f(rowa, rowb):
    merged = []
    idx = 0
    for ela, elb in zip(rowa, rowb):
        if idx >= 4 and idx <= 6:
            newel = ela
        else:
            newel = ela + elb  # I leave the meaning of '+' up to you
        merged.append(newel)       
    return merged

outd = {}
for row in ilist:
    key = (row[4], row[5], row[6])
    storedrow = outd.get(key, None)
    if storedrow is not None:
        outd[key] = f(storedrow, row)
    else:
        outd[key] = row
for k, v in outd.items():
    print k, v
```

Comment: Will this merge three or four duplicates ?

Comment: yes, of course. Any number of duplicates. If the key is in the dictionary (i.e. the row has already been encountered), the values are merged.